# How to evaluate $f(1)$?

Tags: functions

$$f(x+1)-f(x) = 3$$
$$f(19) = 70$$

I'm trying to evaluate $f(1)$ from given data. However, what I noticed so far is that the function is linear.

My attempt:

For $x=19$

$$f(19) = f(20)-3$$

This yields

$$70 = f(20)-3 \implies f(20) = 73$$

Since my goal is to evaluate $f(1)$, it makes no literal sense to proceed from there. Could you assist me?

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Put $\,n=19\,$ in $\,f(n) = f(1) + 3(n-1)\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
f(1) &= f(1) - f(2)+f(2)-f(3)+\ldots-f(19)+f(19)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{18} (f(k)-f(k+1)) + f(19)\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^{18} (f(k+1)-f(k)) + 70\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^{18} 3 + 70\\
&= -3 \cdot 18 + 70 = 16. 
\end{align}

Comment: It's unclear after the summation.

Comment: @Enzo I have added two extra steps. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Yes, unfortunalety It is. So, I think you need to update something with summation since im not familiar with it.

Comment: @Enzo Could you be more precise? Which row of the computation are you not familiar with?

Comment: How did you also obtain $3$?

Comment: @Enzo From your condition, which reads $f(x+1) - f(x) = 3$. But I'm guessing you figured that out since you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We conclude that $$f(x)=3x+a$$for some real $a$ and for $x\in\Bbb N$. Also $$f(19)=70=57+a\to a=13$$and we can obtain$$f(1)=3+13=16$$